# How to assign different data types to NSMutableData

Tags: nsmutabledata

I'm trying to create a vertex attribute array for storing vectors and indices in a mesh. I realise that vertex attributes can be made up from vector2, vector3 and/or vector4 so i'd like to create a class that caters for them all without constraining methods to return a certain type of object. As a test, i've written the following class making use of `NSMutableData`:

```
//VertexAttributeArray.h

@interface VertexAttributeArray : NSObject
{
    NSMutableData *vertexData;
}

- (void *)data;
- (CGRect *)rect;

//VertexAttributeArray.m

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        vertexData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void *)data
{
    return [vertexData mutableBytes];
}

- (CGRect *)rect
{
    return [vertexData mutableBytes];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if(vertexData)
    {
        [vertexData release];
        vertexData = nil;
    }

    [super dealloc];
}
```

From within my mesh class, i'd like to be able to call something like:

```
VertexAttributeArray *vertexAttributeArray = [[VertexAttributeArray alloc] init];

[vertexAttributeArray data][0] = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //doesn't work - compiler error
[vertexAttributeArray rect][0] = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //works fine
```

The first method accessing `data` would be preferred as this doesn't constrain the class to work with a specific type of struct but Xcode just throws the warning "Incomplete type 'void' is not assignable."

I don't want to have multiple methods for different types of data structures but I can't see any way to get around this currently. Having methods that return pointers to different types doesn't look very elegant and adds a lot of vestigial unused (and unwanted) code.

Is there a way to work around this to create an agnostic data store? I'd prefer for my mesh class to have different `VertexAttributeArray` objects to store vertices, indices, normals and colours etc so storing vector2, vector3 and vector4 is ideally where i'd like to be. How would I work around achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want. It's not known at compile-time what size the objects inside `data` is. `((void *)foo)[x]` would be illegal in C as well. The compiler must know what struct is stored inside the array for you to be able to index it.

You can change the call to:

```
((CGRect *)[vertexAttributeArray data])[0] = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

if you prefer, since then it's known that there is `sizeof(CGRect)` distance between the objects inside `data`.

Comment: Wonderful. I thought that might be the case. Thank you very much for your answer.